# Alias with variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create an alias in `bash` like this:

```
alias tail_ls="ls -l $1 | tail"
```

Thus, if somebody types:

```
tail_ls /etc/
```

it will only show the last 10 files in the directory.

But `$1` does not seem to work for me. Is there any way I can introduce variables in bash.

Comment: csh and tcsh support parameters like `$1` in alias; bash doesn't.

Comment: For visitors considering the answers below, the [Bash manual specifically says](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html) *"If arguments are needed, use a shell function"*.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

I'd create a function for that, rather than alias, and then exported it, like this:

```
function tail_ls { ls -l "$1" | tail; }

export -f tail_ls
```

Note `-f` switch to `export`: it tells it that you are exporting a function. Put this in your `.bashrc` and you are good to go.

Comment: It's usually not necessary to export a function.

Comment: @Dennis, yeah, you are right, for a simple alias that won't be necessary, but it is there just in case you want to use it in some derived shell/process.

Comment: Why do I need an alias if I can call the function directly?

Comment: This is not an alias-base solution, its a function-base solution .. It's working smoothly

Comment: Technically almost everything is a file to Linux, so functions are files, alias & tail are files, even processes are files.

Answer (score 43):

```
alias tail_ls='_tail_ls() { ls -l "$1" | tail ;}; _tail_ls'
```

Comment: That's a creative approach. Definitely solves the issue if they **need** to use an alias rather than a function… I think I'd prefer a function if those are an option instead, but a very neat solution to keep in mind for when the right situation arises!

Answer (score 38):

The solution of @maxim-sloyko did not work, but if the following:

1. In ~/.bashrc add:

   ```
   sendpic () { scp "$@" mina@foo.bar.ca:/www/misc/Pictures/; }
   ```
2. Save the file and reload

   ```
   $ source ~/.bashrc
   ```
3. And execute:

   ```
   $ sendpic filename.jpg
   ```

original source: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/command_aliases.htm

Comment: @jruzafa, In which context, you assert that 'The solution of maxim-sloyko works did not work' whilst his/her solution worked for myself.

Comment: You can add your functions to bashrc with: `typeset -f >> ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 4):

You can define `$1` with `set`, then use your alias as intended:

```
$ alias tail_ls='ls -l "$1" | tail'
$ set mydir
$ tail_ls
```

Comment: What is set doing here? How does this work?

Comment: @Brijesh, `set mydir` defines `$1` as `mydir` that would be the intended directory... not that great.

Answer (score 3):

`tail_ls() { ls -l "$1" | tail; }`

Comment: Please fix the syntax error (missing `;` before `}`) and double-quote `$1` so as to also support filenames with embedded whitespace and other shell metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Fish shell (from http://fishshell.com ) instead of bash, they write functions a little differently.

You'll want to add something like this to your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` which is the equivalent of your `~/.bashrc`

```
function tail_ls
  ls -l $1 | tail
end
```