# Why does variable expansion within an alias work "as intended" in only one of these cases?

Tags: bash, variables, alias

This question was inspired in part by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438147/alias-with-variable-in-bash).

```
alias foo='ls -1 $1'
foo /etc
```

displays the contents of /etc, one item per line.

```
ls -1 /etc | tail
```

displays the last ten items in /etc.

But

```
alias foo='ls -1 $1 | tail'
foo /etc
```

displays: tail: error reading `/etc': Is a directory

Answer (score 14):

I have found variable expansion in aliases to be flaky, and not recommended:
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases

Use a function instead: `function foo() { ls -1 $1; }`

Comment: This is the definitively correct answer. To quote from the bash manual @speeves referenced:
" There is NO MECHANISM [my emphasis] for using arguments in the replacement text, as in csh. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used (see Shell Functions)."

I've found that the only places that a variable "works" is if it's at the end of the alias text, which implies that your additional text is just getting added to the end of the alias command, rather than being replaced in the text.

In other words, if you have used a variable and it worked, you're just lucky.

Answer (score 3):

Aliases done this way will only expand from the set of parameters:

```
$ alias foo='ls -1 $1 | tail'
$ foo .
# Type Esc-C-e: this expands aliases/globs/environment variables...
# ... And the result of the expansion is:
$ ls -1  | tail .
# $1 has disappeared
$ set bar  # set $1...
$ foo . # again, Esc-C-e
$ ls -1 bar | tail .
```

Comment: Thanks; why does the variable work in the simple first alias without the pipe but disappear in the second alias?

Comment: I have fixed my answer: actually the `$` in aliases will try and expand from `$*`, ie the set of arguments the shell was launched with. See post edit.

Comment: Thanks again, but I am still looking for an explanation of the why the first alias works OK but not the second.

Comment: It is because `$1` is undefined -- try and `set xxxxx`, then your first alias again: you'll get `ls: xxxxx: no such file or directory`

Comment: I guess I don't understand:  if in my first code in the original question I insert `set xxxxx` between the alias definition and usage, there is no change in the output.

Comment: If you have a file named `xxxx`, no. If there is there will definitely be. Try and redirect stdout to `/dev/null` to see.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question: it is luck that the first case matches what you expect.

You have written your aliases assuming that $1 will represent the first "argument" to your alias. In fact, aliases in bash do not accept arguments, they merely replace the alias text with the stuff in quotes that you assigned it.  So what does your $1 actually do?

Separate from aliases, in bash, `$0` expands to the first thing typed to being the script or shell you are in (the command).  `$1` is the first argument (or second thing typed).  Since you are typing in a shell at the command line, your shell was likely started by a terminal or window manager running the command `bash` with no arguments.

Try this from the command line:

```
$ echo $0
bash
$ echo $1
# prints nothing
```

So in your first case,
 `foo /etc` 
expands foo to get
 `ls -1 $1 /etc` 
and since $1 is null,

`ls -1 /etc`

also, if you pipe that to tail by adding `| tail` it works fine.

In your 2nd case
 `foo /etc` 
expands foo to get
 `ls -1 $1 | tail /etc` 
and since $1 is null,

`ls -1 | tail /etc`

which gives that error you got, because the command after the pipe is in error: `tail` cannot operate on the directory `/etc`

Answer (score 0):

Because `$1` expands to nothing, it doesn't hold anything. In both cases the parameter `/etc` is appended to the last command. So, the first case doesn't result in `ls -1 /etc`, but in `ls -1 $1 /etc`, which is never the less meaningful. And the second string results in `tail /etc`, which is erroneous.