# Terminal: How do I pass arguments into an alias?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

In a directory which is added to my $PATH I have the following file:

```
filename="$1" day="$2" month="$3"
ruby -r "./SomeClass.rb" -e 'SomeClass.run($filename, $day, $month)'
```

Suppose this file is called someclass. When I type someclass into terminal my system recognizes it as a valid command and runs the corresponding Ruby file correctly. But the arguments are not being passed in. How do I pass arguments into an alias?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I pass arguments into an alias?

Don't use an `alias`, better to declare a `function` for this. You can pass arguments and do other stuff easily inside a bash function:

```
someclass() {
   # make sure enough arguments are passed in
   # echo "$1 - $2 - $3";
   filename="$1"; day="$2"; month="$3";
   ruby -r "./SomeClass.rb" -e "SomeClass.run($filename, $day, $month)";
}
```

Comment: @anishsane: Thanks for making that important quote change, I did a bad copy/paste from question.

Comment: How are you declaring a function? Is this a scripting language? Or does bash have this kind of functionality built into itself?

Comment: This is totally supported in BASH itself. You can place this code in your `~/.bashrc` and then function becomes available anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are using single quote. Change them to double:

```
ruby -r "./SomeClass.rb" -e "SomeClass.run($filename, $day, $month)"
```

No expansion are done within single quotes. From [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html):

> 3.1.2.2 Single Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> 3.1.2.3 Double Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’. The characters ‘$’ and ‘`’ retain their special meaning within double quotes (see Shell Expansions). The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘"’, ‘\’, or newline. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without a special meaning are left unmodified. A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an ‘!’ appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the ‘!’ is not removed.

A useful page on quotes I am using is on [grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html).

Regarding the title of the question, check [this question (Alias with variable in bash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438147/alias-with-variable-in-bash) and its answer: you can't and have to use functions.