# Text-to-speech from the command line via cloud API

Tags: bash, curl, command-line-interface, string-interpolation

I am trying to define a one-liner alias like the following:

```
alias speak='curl -G --data-urlencode "text=$(cat /dev/stdin)" "https://speech.botiumbox.com/api/tts/en?&tts=marytts" -H "accept: audio/wav" | mpv -'
```

such that I can use it like this

```
echo Hello World! | speak
speak Hello World!
speak<RET> # continuously do TTS per line until ^D
Hello World!
Another line!
<Ctrl-D>
```

The API I am using works if I use

```
curl -G --data-urlencode "text=Hello World!" "https://speech.botiumbox.com/api/tts/en?&tts=marytts" -H "accept: audio/wav" | mpv -
```

As demonstrated above, simply taking the standard input by `cat /dev/stdin` didn't seem to create a interactive CLI program. Any ideas to wrap this API into an interactive CLI program? Ideally, be POSIX compliant so it can run in a `bash` shell in Unixen.

Comment: You may take advantage from [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/), [Alias with variable in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438147/) or [How to properly use $1 in an alias?](https://superuser.com/questions/295150/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround that uses bash functions instead of an alias. The function `marySpeak` takes a string, sends it online for TTS then plays it back with `mpv`. Everything is defined as a oneliner, so can be placed in your `.bashrc`:

```sh
marySpeak() { curl -s -G --data-urlencode "text=$1" "https://speech.botiumbox.com/api/tts/en?&tts=marytts" -H "accept: audio/wav" | mpv - 2>&1 > /dev/null; } 

# then simply use it like this
marySpeak "hello world!"
```

Tested in GNU/Linux and macOS.