# How do I pass a variable to a bash alias easier nmap scanning? (Function, alias, script…?)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zshrc, zsh-alias

Been poking around for a bit trying to find a straight answer but VScode keeps giving me grief when checking the syntax and the alias doesn't seem to work.

I often switch between networks with devices that aren't easily discoverable and their IP addresses often change. I've found myself using `nmap` to quickly scan the network devices for the ports I'm looking for (e.g. `22 open ssh` when working with a pi).

For example…

```
qmap11='nmap -sn 192.168.1.1/24'
qmap21='nmap -sn 192.168.2.1/24'
qmap31='nmap -sn 192.168.3.1/24'
```

As you can imagine this isn't the cleanest way to do this, and I want to run something like the following

```
$ qmap 3
# to run nmap -sn 192.168.3.1/24
```

Or…

```
$ qmap ip
# to run something like nmap -sn [whatever subnet I'm on]
# so I don't have to first check what the network is
```

I've been tinkering with building a function… but want to figure this out first.

Other Posts:

[Alias with variable in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438147/alias-with-variable-in-bash)

[Linux bash script to extract IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336126/linux-bash-script-to-extract-ip-address)

[Which terminal command to get just IP address and nothing else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529181/which-terminal-command-to-get-just-ip-address-and-nothing-else)

[How to detect the OS from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394230/how-to-detect-the-os-from-a-bash-script/18434831)

[Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter)

*Theser other posts definitely hint at what I'm tryingn to figure out.*

Comment: how do you get from `[qmap] 3` to `192.168.3.1/24`? sure, I could guess `192.168.?.1/24` but then how do you get to `100 192.168.1.1/24` from `qmap ??` ? how do you determine `whatever subnet I'm on`? what code have you tried so far? [please update the question with these additional details]

Comment: I suggest to use a function.

Comment: @markp-fuso - The `qmap 3` is what I'm trying to build. The prior examples are above. e.g. `qmap31='nmap -sn 192.168.3.1/24'` - Note that this is an alias, with a hardcoded IP address of `192.168.3.1/24` - Or something like `qmap -s 3` to replace the x in `192.168.X.1/24`

Comment: You can't aliases for this. You **must** use a function instead. Aliases can only do prefix substitution and nothing else.

Comment: Please don't turn the question into an answer. Your question should remain strictly a question. I have rolled back your recent edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a function.

```
qmap() {
   nmap -sn "192.168.$1.1/24"
}
```