# Create alias (with variable) without using functions in Bash?

Tags: bash, alias

What can I do to make this alias working good?

```
alias mcd="echo Go to  $1 ; cd $1"
```

When I write `alias mcd="echo Go to  $1"` - than Go to  work normally. If I add `cd $1` the alias works, but doesn't print the name of the directory, value of `$1=""` for first part of alias. How to solve this?

Separately both parts os alias work, but together - no.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438147/alias-with-variable-in-bash), but it's 8 years old. Is it possible to do this without using a function?

Comment: Functions are the right tool for this job. Aliases are the wrong one. Do you have a **practical** reason for the constraint?

Comment: (to be explicit: no, nothing has changed that invalidates the linked question's answers over the last decade; aliases being considered bad practice goes back a lot further than that, too).

Comment: BTW, you can see the history of the bash IRC channel's factoid database on the topic at https://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/alias; as you can see, some variant on "If you have to ask, you probably want to use a function instead" has always been the standard advice.

Comment: Aliases in bash don't take parameters. All the parameters are appended to the expanded alias, for anything more complex you need a function.

Comment: Now, if there's a practical constraint you need a workaround for, we can try to build that workaround for you -- but we need to know exactly _why_ functions are impractical to use in your current scenario: if we don't know the letter of the rules you're being evaluated against, we don't know which mechanics will work to skirt them. (For example, one can embed a function within an alias, or have an alias start a whole new shell interpreter). Whereas if it's just a matter of curiosity, that's off topic here; see the "practical" criteria in https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Thank you, everything is clear... What do you advise if the question is still relevant to me (I'm just curious to find a solution)